# Reputation removal on irrelvant/false answers - negative and positive

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was trying to help someone today by answering their question. The question was poorly asked, but I mentioned a couple different things that could potentially fix it. After several comments on my answer between the OP and I, OP finally discovered the solution was something totally irrelevant to their question (which of course makes my answer irrelevant). However, throughout the time I was helping, I had gotten a couple vote-ups (sweet), and OP even gave me the accepted answer (to be nice?). Anyway, a couple hours later, my rep dropped out of nowhere and I noticed my answer was gone! I lost all the points for that answer. I assume a mod saw this and deleted it. What is up with that? Am I wrong to say that I don't think that is right? I spent a good amount of time trying to help this person, when their issue had nothing to do with their question. So now not only did they waste my time, but I don't get the rep I gained either? I have seen enough voted-up irrelevant answers to know that isn't fair.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077382/sql-count-issues

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: I'd have to try to search it, it's no longer in my answers history.

Comment: Hm, it could be that the question was deleted (which deletes its answers, obviously). If that's the case you should consider it a lesson in not wasting time answering bad questions. Tough, but that's the way it is. - btw there's a "show removed posts" checkbox in the [reputation tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167257/shredder?tab=reputation) in your profile, did you check it?

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077382/sql-count-issues. Guess my answer was converted to a comment..

Comment: What? [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10077457/99456) is still there...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: I rolled it all back. It had two upvotes and the accepted checkmark, so conversion seems unrealistic.

Comment: For "completeness" sake it would be ideal if you'll edit your answer and add the actual solution posted in the comments. This way it will be safe from wandering moderators or keen users flagging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rolled back the deletion, but it's probably a lost cause... The question itself is too localized.

Thanks for helping the OP out, though.

Comment: @Shredder: Well, if you're *only* here for the reputation, yes. If you'd genuinely like to help the person out realizing that the question is probably too localized and likely to be deleted, then no, you should continue helping. :)

Comment: @Shredder, think of it this way: The experience you gain solving a tricky and specific problem will help you in your career much more than a few rep points. Not to mention that warm fuzzy feeling you get for helping someone out =).